# Como revertir el resultado de un filtro de búsqueda en linux (bash)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Tengo un directorio que contiene varios tipos de archivos

```
file.json
file.txt
file.py
file.html
file.R
```

Deseo listar todos aquellos que no sean txt.
Con el comando `ls *.txt` puedo listar los txt, pero ¿como hago para listar todo lo que no sea txt?

Comment: ¿Has mirado si el `man ls` te ofrece alguna ayuda acerca de los parámetros de **ls**?  Diría que debes buscar el parámetro `--hide` para lograr lo que tu quieres.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando el modificador `-I`

```
ls -I "*.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar los argumentos de `find`:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-basic -not -regex ".*\.txt$"
```

El truco lo hacen los argumentos `-not -regex "..."`, donde solo evitan listar los archivos con sufijo ".txt".

También puedes usar un *pipe*:

```
$ ls | grep -v ".txt"
```

Como sea, me parece que la opción más *al grano* es la de @alfabravo.